# gettimeofday() does not fill its timeval argument

Tags: c, macos, time

I'm testing if I could use `gettimeofday()` to measure the performance of a piece of code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
  struct timeval *tp_begin;
  gettimeofday(tp_begin, NULL);
  if (tp_begin == NULL) printf("tp_begin: Strange...\n");

  struct timeval *tp_end;
  gettimeofday(tp_end, NULL);
  if (tp_end == NULL) printf("tp_end: Strange...\n");

  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles (with `gcc -g test.c -o test`), and I would expect nothing to be printed `stdout`, but here's the output:

```
tp_end: Strange...
```

I've tried running this multiple times, but the result is always the same. What's going on here?

Comment: `struct timeval tp_begin; gettimeofday(&tp_begin, NULL);` same for `tp_end`. Answer yourself this `"What valid block of memory is tp_begin pointing to when I use it?"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing an uninitialized pointer to the function.  The result could be anything at all, it is undefined behavior.

To get a result from `gettimeofday`, you are required to pass a valid pointer to a buffer which the function will fill in.  The function does not provide the buffer (it couldn't even if it wanted to, because the pointer argument is passed by value).

Comment: Thank you, I tried allocating a buffer to each pointer and it works!
`struct timeval *tp_end = (struct timeval *)malloc(sizeof(struct timeval));`

Comment: @MinhPhúcLê: There's no need for dynamic allocation.  Just use `&` to get a pointer to your variable, as in `struct timeval tp_end; gettimeofday(&tp_end, 0);`

Comment: Yes I'm aware that your suggestion works before posting the question, I just want to know why declaring a pointer does not work while declaring a struct works. Turns out it's the uninitialized pointer problem you explained in your answer.